# Algebra of Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image]

My attempt

a) False.

example $\{-1^n\}$

b) False

Take $a_n=(-1)^n$ and  $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}$ then $a_n+b_n $ is constant zero sequence hence convergent but both $a_n$ and $ b_n$ are divergent.

c) False

Take $a_n$ and $b_n$ both to be $(-1)^n$

d) False

Same example as in b) will work.

e) False

Same example as in c) will work.

f) True

Sum theorem

g) False

Take $a_n=0$  and $b_n=(-1)^n$

Am I right ?

Comment: They all look correct to me.

Comment: Everything is fine.